# SQL Delete Rows with Subquery and NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query to return duplicate rows with a certain status. The query is returning correctly, but I additionally need to delete the rows from Table1 as well. When I change my SELECT into a DELETE statement through it deletes all records, not just the subset based on my query. What am I doing wrong? Here is the query that is returning the rows expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID_1 ORDER BY Status) RowNumber
    FROM Table1
) X
WHERE (((X.RowNumber > 1) and (X.Status = 1)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X.ID_1 = Table2.ID_2))
```

Now I want to just delete the results of the above query, but the below deletes all records from Table1:

```
DELETE Table1
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID_1 ORDER BY Status) RowNumber
    FROM Table1
) X
WHERE (((X.RowNumber > 1) and (X.Status = 1)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X.ID_1 = Table2.ID_2))
```

Comment: Should be `DELETE X` the derived table / sub query name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Squrirrel` mentioned in the the comment I have tested your code with some dummy data and I found it works. Change `DELETE Table1` into `DELETE X`. Here is my sample code what works for me.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID_1 INT,INFO VARCHAR(20),[Status] SMALLINT);
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(ID_2 INT,INFO VARCHAR(20),[Status] SMALLINT);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,'a',1);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,'b',1);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,'a',2);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1,'b',2);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2,'a',1);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2,'b',1);
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(2,'b',1);

DELETE X
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID_1 ORDER BY Status) RowNumber
    FROM @Table1
) X
WHERE (((X.RowNumber > 1) and (X.Status = 1)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Table2 t2 WHERE X.ID_1 = t2.ID_2));
```

Comment: You have two `FROM` in your query

Comment: I mean here `DELETE FROM X FROM (...` should be just `DELETE X FROM (...`

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks for correcting me. It was a typing mistake . :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use common table expression to delete from  source table while deleting the results only. Try below code:

```
with  X as (

    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID_1 ORDER BY Status) RowNumber
    FROM Table1
) 
Delete X
WHERE (((X.RowNumber > 1) and (X.Status = 1)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X.ID_1 = Table2.ID_2))
```